# single ajax requests to server, trying to reuse object multiple times in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have created an image gallery for products and have 2 different views on it. Each time a view is selected an ajax request is sent to the server and a json object returned. My code currently works but im concerned that it could be made faster, and im not sure if $.empty() really clears the json object from memory.

The code:

```
<div id=grid2></div>
<div id=grid4></div>
<section id=maindisplay> 

$.ajax({   // DEFAULT VIEW                                    
  url: 'query.php',                          
  data: "",                         
  dataType: 'json',                      
  success: ajaxfunction
}); 

function ajaxfunction(json_data){
  console.log (json_data) 
  //format json_data here in to a table
  $("#maindisplay").append(table);
}

$("#grid2").click(function(){
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'query.php',                            
    data: "",                        
    dataType: 'json',                     
    success: ajaxfunction2
  });
});

function ajaxfunction2(json_data){  //ONE OF THE GRID VIEWS
  $("#maindisplay").empty();
  console.log (json_data) 
  //format json_data here in to a table
  $("#maindisplay").append(table);
}

</section>
```

I have tried but can I make another object locally with the json data for reuse without making another call?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you wan't to retrieve the JSON data and reference to it several times? If so then yes you can, you just need to create a variable before the ajax request is sent and then assign the data to that variable. Similar to the below.

```
var jsonData;
$.ajax({                                 
  url: 'query.php',                          
  data: "",                         
  dataType: 'json',                      
  success: function(data){
     jsonData = data;
     ajaxfunction(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a simple question of variable scope, not ajax *per se*.